# Recursion using repeat controls and custom controls

Tags: xpages

I am trying to generate a hierarchical list of categories and sub-categories on an X-Page. So far I have attempted two methods:

The first, which works, is based on code by Jesse Gallagher [in this blog post](http://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/basic-org-charts-with-xe-navigator-and-xe-beantreenode) and that outputs the list in exactly the order I want it using an xe:outline control. However, I want be able to add extra functions and styling to each entry (e.g. edit and delete links) but can't work out how to render custom controls within the outline control.

The second method is trying to leverage nested repeats and custom controls to generate the list but for the life of me I can't quite get this work and I don't know if it's because it just won't work or I'm just missing something fundamental. The basic code for the XPage is:

```xml
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="Categories" viewName="vLUTopCat"></xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>

<xc:ccUI navigationPath="Admin/Main" pageName="Admin">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel xp:key="facetMiddle">
        <h2>Categories</h2>             
            <ul id="adminCatList">
                <xp:repeat id="parentCat" rows="30" value="#{Categories}" var="DocCat" indexVar="catIdx" disableOutputTag="true">                       
                    <xc:ccCategoryList>
                        <xc:this.catID><![CDATA[#{javascript:DocCat.getColumnValue("docID")}]]></xc:this.catID>
                        <xc:this.catName><![CDATA[#{javascript:DocCat.getColumnValue("categoryName")}]]></xc:this.catName>
                    </xc:ccCategoryList>                                            
                </xp:repeat>
            </ul>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:ccUI>
```

and the code for the custom control (ccCategoryList) is:

```xml
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">


<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
    value="#{compositeData.catName}" tagName="li" />
<xp:repeat id="rptSubCat" rows="30" var="subCat"
    disableOutputTag="true">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="header"
            escape="false">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[<ul>]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="footer"
            escape="false">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[</ul>]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var tview = database.getView("vLUSubCat");
var v = compositeData.catID;
var vc:NotesViewEntryCollection = null;
if (v != null) {
vc = tview.getAllEntriesByKey(v);
}
vc}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xc:ccCategoryList>
        <xc:this.catID><![CDATA[#{javascript:subCat.getColumnValues()[3]}]]></xc:this.catID>
        <xc:this.catName><![CDATA[#{javascript:subCat.getColumnValues()[1]}]]></xc:this.catName>
    </xc:ccCategoryList>
</xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

So my related questions are:

1. Is there anyway to output a custom control in an xe:outline control using a bean node?
2. Can I use repeats and custom controls to recursively output data from views like I can using a bean node?
3. Is there a better alternative method I'm overlooking (e.g. using a Java Collection in a bean and a repeat control?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) There is a way to add your own CustomNode to the Outline For that look [into](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_Basic_UI_Control_for_XPages) extending:

```
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.ITreeNode;
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexLeafTreeNode;
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.impl.TreeNodeWrapper;
```

2) sorry i have never tryed to build a recursive xpage element as a custom Control, but i would not recoment it.

3) You could just use the `<xe:forumView>` or the `<xp:viewPanel>` both have nice possibilites to determine if the `viewEntry`/row is a Category or not. And offers you the possebility to add everything you want like links, buttons or other controls to a row.

or another way to get what you need is to build you Outline/TreeView with the DojoTreeView:
[Link1](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/Tree#id13)
[Link2](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Tree-examples.html#id7)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Michael. I'm coming to the conclusion that I may have to build my own control but only as a last resort if there's nothing that already does what I want it to do.

Comment: have you tried the `<xe:forumView>`? As i can see you use a view as a datasource why not using a viewControl to display you data.

Comment: I was trying to re-edit the previous comment after inadvertantly submitting it early! :(

The ForumView I did consider but at the moment the relationship between categories is not maintained in a traditional Notes parent-child hierarchy but is more like having multiple SQL tables connected by JOINs - very much like Jesse's org chart view. But I haven't entirely ruled it out going back to using a view yet if necessary. (This is one of those scenarios where I know exactly how to do it in PHP and mySQL and am convinced I should be able to do it in XPages as well, if that makes sense.)